# How can i count how many lines in this file and open urls

Tags: python

I have txt file:

```
https://www.google.com/
https://amazon.com/
https://stackoverflow.com/
```

How can i count how many lines in this file and open urls for these times

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

That depends on what exactly you mean by "open" a URL. This bit of code demonstrates how you can read each line from a text file, then access the each line contains and display the HTTP response code:

```py
import requests

with open('file_of_urls.txt', 'r', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()

print(f'read {len(lines)} lines from the file:')

for line in lines:
    url = line.strip()
    r = requests.get(url)
    print(f' {r.status_code} status code from {url}')
```

Output:

```
read 3 lines from the file:
 200 status code from https://www.google.com/
 503 status code from https://amazon.com/
 200 status code from https://stackoverflow.com/
```